# How to change stream metadata with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have many video files and part of it have wrong size, or at least ffmpeg reports wrong size.
For example, ffmpeg prints:

```
 Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2009-10-11 15:04:33
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.3 2008112300
 Duration: 01:47:42.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 663 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x464 [
SAR 43:36 DAR 215:116], 499 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 48k tbn, 50 tbc
 Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2009-10-11 15:04:33
    handler_name    :
 Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 159
kb/s
 Metadata:
     creation_time   : 2009-10-11 15:04:33
     handler_name    :
```

However, when I configure media player to play the file without resizing it has 860x464 size.

I want to write scripts that will fix the files, but I don't know how to do that. I've updated to last ffmpeg version and tried to use -metadata:s:v:0 Video="...860x464...", as I read in ffmpegh doc, but it doesn't work.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably dealing with **Anamorphic widescreen**.

The "true" dimensions of the video are **860x464**, which comes out to a 1.85:1 aspect ratio. The trouble is that DVD image frame have these max sizes.

- PAL 720x576
- NTSC 720x480

If this video was resized while maintaining aspect ratio, you get 720x388. Instead of doing that the author records at **720x464**. This way you fit in the dimensions and maximize the quality. Obviously, recording like this messes up the aspect ratio. Anamorphic video has a "switch" inside it; when the DVD reads this switch it expands the video horizontally to **860x464**.

## Links

- [Anamorphic widescreen](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphic_widescreen)
- [Aspect ratio](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_%28image%29)
- [DVD-Video](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video)